# org.jso.JSONException value <Html> type.java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject

Tags: java, php, android, sql, json

I'm trying to build login page in Android application using Php and MSSQL. Unfortunately, when I try to login, the error appear: 
 org.jso.JSONException value  type.java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonobject

Here is my Login2.php code:

```
<?php
$response = array();
include 'connect.php';


//Get the input request parameters
$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');
$input = json_decode($inputJSON, TRUE); //convert JSON into array

//Check for Mandatory parameters
if(isset($input['etLoginUsername']) && isset($input['etLoginPassword'])){
    $username = $input['etLoginUsername'];
    $password = $input['etLoginPassword'];
    $query    = "SELECT * FROM TestingUser WHERE PF_No = ?";

    if($stmt = $conn ->prepare($query)){
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$username);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->bind_result($PF_No,$Name);
        if($stmt->fetch()){


                $response["status"] = 0;
                $response["message"] = "Login successful";
                $response["Name"] = $Name;
                $response["PF_No"] = $PF_No;
        }
        else{
            $response["status"] = 1;
            $response["message"] = "Invalid username and password combination";
        }

        $stmt->close();
    }
}
else{
    $response["status"] = 2;
    $response["message"] = "Missing mandatory parameters";
}
//Display the JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

SessionHandler.java:

```
package com.example.androidtransformer;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

import java.util.Date;

/**
 * Created by Abhi on 20 Jan 2018 020.
 */

public class SessionHandler {
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "UserSession";
    private static final String KEY_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String KEY_EXPIRES = "expires";
    private static final String KEY_FULL_NAME = "full_name";
    private static final String KEY_EMPTY = "";
    private Context mContext;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor mEditor;
    private SharedPreferences mPreferences;

    public SessionHandler(Context mContext) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        mPreferences = mContext.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        this.mEditor = mPreferences.edit();
    }

    /**
     * Logs in the user by saving user details and setting session
     *
     * @param username
     * @param fullName
     */
    public void loginUser(String username, String fullName) {
        mEditor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        mEditor.putString(KEY_FULL_NAME, fullName);
        Date date = new Date();

        //Set user session for next 7 days
        long millis = date.getTime() + (7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        mEditor.putLong(KEY_EXPIRES, millis);
        mEditor.commit();
    }

    /**
     * Checks whether user is logged in
     *
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        Date currentDate = new Date();

        long millis = mPreferences.getLong(KEY_EXPIRES, 0);

        /* If shared preferences does not have a value
         then user is not logged in
         */
        if (millis == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        Date expiryDate = new Date(millis);

        /* Check if session is expired by comparing
        current date and Session expiry date
        */
        return currentDate.before(expiryDate);
    }

    /**
     * Fetches and returns user details
     *
     * @return user details
     */
    public User getUserDetails() {
        //Check if user is logged in first
        if (!isLoggedIn()) {
            return null;
        }
        User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(mPreferences.getString(KEY_USERNAME, KEY_EMPTY));
        user.setFullName(mPreferences.getString(KEY_FULL_NAME, KEY_EMPTY));
        user.setSessionExpiryDate(new Date(mPreferences.getLong(KEY_EXPIRES, 0)));

        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Logs out user by clearing the session
     */
    public void logoutUser(){
        mEditor.clear();
        mEditor.commit();
    }

}
```

MySingleton.java (for volley request)

```
package com.example.androidtransformer;

import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

/**
 * Created by Abhi on 20 Jan 2018 020.
 */

public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private MySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
}
```

Login.java

```
package com.example.androidtransformer;

import android.content.Context;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

/**
 * Created by Abhi on 20 Jan 2018 020.
 */

public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private MySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    private RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }
}
```

activity_login.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#304769"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="50dp"
    tools:context=".Login">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_white" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etLoginUsername"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="@string/username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:padding="10dp" />


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/etLoginPassword"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogin"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#f05924"
        android:text="@string/sign_in"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/not_having_account"
        android:textColor="#ccc" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLoginRegister"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="#aaa"
        android:text="@string/register"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Are you getting an error while sending data to server or while receiving from server? Also please share the JSON structure you are using to send/receive

Comment: @VinayJayaram I think the error is while receiving from server as it stated the data can't be converted into JsonObject. what do you mean by Json structure?

Comment: is the server working in any of other REST clients like POSTMAN?

Comment: @VinayJayaram No sir.

Comment: It should work in POSTMAN or any other REST clients. Then only it would work in android